# Flutter build error : Lost connection to device

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I cannot build with the following error message both iOS and Android.

```
Lost connection to device.
Exited (sigterm)
```

I try `flutter doctor -v`

```
-> % flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.3, on macOS 12.2.1 21D62 darwin-arm, locale ja-JP)
    • Flutter version 2.10.3 at /Users/hoge/develop/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 7e9793dee1 (5 days ago), 2022-03-02 11:23:12 -0600
    • Engine revision bd539267b4
    • Dart version 2.16.1
    • DevTools version 2.9.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/hoge/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Users/hoge/Downloads/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at /Users/hoge/Downloads/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.65.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.36.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • iPhone 11 (mobile) • F79C5603-6113-4998-AEF8-97D7BEF5C4FB • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-15-2 (simulator)
    • Chrome (web)       • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 99.0.4844.51
    ! Error:  Xcode will continue when iPhone is connected. (code -13)

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

If anyone knows a solution, please let me know.

Comment: Could you open the .xcworkspace file under the "iOS/" folder in Xcode and build and run with Xcode itself and see the results?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the following method solved the problem.
(This may have been a specific problem with my device)

- Uninstalling the app on the emulator and then building it solved the problem.